# Start/Stop service on ubuntu using php

Tags: php, ubuntu

#### Hey!

I have tried adding www-data to sudoers and much more but still the www-data user has not the permission to start/stop services. Strangly i can display the status. What am I doing wrong?

*Thanks in advance! :)*

Comment: sudoers is not the only group needed at a guess, but never needed to do this myself. I would suggest http://askubuntu.com/ as this is a coding stack, this question is kinda between both stacks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What rjdown means is.... **You've done a VERY BAD THING!!!**

This means that any hacker or knowledgeable person could execute a script on your server and take full control!

Never set www-data as a sudo.. Rarely you even need to make such changes to that user if ever.

I would suggest something more like having PHP execute a python or bash script which then executes the service commands.. This way you allow PHP to only run a single script which is restricted to only what you code in it.

If you wish to take this approach, i would suggest reading something like http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/ and using the `runuser` method or similar.

This way your restricting www-data to only being allowed to run the script you want.

Comment: Okay thanks will try (I do know about that, it is why i restricted only to execute the init.d script which i wanted)

Comment: Thanks for the link was really helpful

Comment: Rather you not be bitten by someone exploring to much within your website/server. Glad to be of help